How to Ensure State Consistency When Using React Context and Asynchronous setState?
I want to maintain the filter values, which are key value pairs in a global context to support app wide state.
const createFilterContext = (defaultFilters: FilterState = {}) => {
const FilterContext = React.createContext<FilterContextType | undefined>(undefined);

const FilterProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState<FilterState>(defaultFilters);

const setFilter = (key: string, value: any) => {
  setFilters((prevFilters) => ({ ...prevFilters, [key]: value }));
};

const clearFilters = () => {
  setFilters(defaultFilters);
};

return (
  <FilterContext.Provider value={{ filters, setFilter, clearFilters }}>
    {children}
  </FilterContext.Provider>
);
};

There is a filter panel which shows all the filter controls
const FilterPanel = ({ filterControls, onApply }: FilterPanelProps) => { }
<FilterPanel filterControls={filterControls} onApply={fetchDataWithFilters} />
FilterControls are some kind of input elements like dropdown, slider, checkbox etc.
onApply is passed by the pages that use FilterPanel. It will run when Apply Filters button in Filter Panel is clicked and will fetch Data with the applied key value pairs as query params to backend.
Now the problem here is React setState is asynchronous. So if I change some filter input control, and immediately click Apply Filters, the context state will be yet to update with the new value from that input control and makes fetch call without the new value.
My real code is much bigger and complex. I have simplified it here.
Please help me with your suggestions. Is my design bad? How can I solve this problem?
CodeSandbox Demo Link
In codesandbox project, I have directly called fetch method immediately after state update code in filter controls, as it was too fast since it is light weight app with fewer lines of code and calling fetch on click of Apply Filters button gives it sufficient time to get new state.
In my Real Large code base it takes few milliseconds for state update and I get the issue when Apply Filters button is pressed.

Looks good only. Where is the fetch you make? Just make sure fetch is based on context value. If you can create a sandbox repro that would be amazing

@TusharShahi sure I will make a sandbox and comment here.

@TusharShahi added codesandbox link

One issue with the repproduction is that since you are calling applyFilters immediately, it does not have the latest context value. It will always be one cycle behind. Hence we cannot say it is a proper example reproduction, because this can be fixed with just moving the code to its right place

Even if your code base is large, can you paste here the essential parts of the component which call applyFilters

@TusharShahi In the codesandbox, you can open the console to see logs. I removed the immediate call. So here in the web page, if you click on the blue button, you see a logs of fetch call. This is the exact simulation of my code base. In real one, there are multiple scenarios like on top, a row of header filter buttons, and also side panel buttons etc. This code sandbox is exact simulation but with simple components.

@TusharShahi but here I don't see the issue, the state update seems to be immediate. Codesandbox seems to be very fast or may be due to light weight application. But in theory we do know they can be delay and outdated values in context state(setState is batched for latest state). So I want to solve this issue.

@TusharShahi, when the onApply function in User.tsx is triggered, the last state update could be batched, and not executed before onChange event handler in User.tsx runs. That is what I thought when I was seeing the issue in my real code.
Are you saying  setState is guranteed to be executed and update the state just because it was triggered before onApply is executed(on click of the apply button) ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"if I change some filter input control, and immediately click Apply Filters, the context state will be yet to update with the new value from that input control and makes fetch call without the new value." - please post the code of that, in particular the click handler that updates the context state and also calls onApply, and the fetchDataWithFilters code that does make the fetch call.

Most likely you have a stale closure problem here where in fetchDataWithFilters you are directly accessing the context state. This can be solved by either a) not accessing the context state in fetchDataWithFilters but passing the new value as a parameter or b) not using an onApply prop at all, but rather calling fetchDataWithFilters from a useEffect that has the context state as a dependency

@Bergi in the question I have given codesandbox link. In that Users.tsx has onApply function where the fetch call will be made (I have added it as comment).
Is it a bad design? And I understood the useEffect solution above, can you please explain the first one? - a) not accessing the context state in fetchDataWithFilters but passing the new value as a parameter.

React useState state updater function is a completely pure and synchronous function. It's not clear to me really what your post is about, especially if you are basing assumptions on false premises. Please [edit] to clarify the issue or problem and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

From the above question, I understand that, on apply you are updating the setState and passing the updated filter values to your API Service as a params.
To better way to handle that situation is to, add a callback inside that API service and then pass the actual parameter as an argument to that service and also pass your setState. So, if your API gets successful, it will also update your state with that value [Don't depend on the state value on Apply. Depend on the state value for the initial time only]. This will fix your error.
Example: onApply Function
const onApply = async (appliedFilters: FilterProps) => {
    await fetchFilteredData(appliedFIlters, setFilter)
}

Example: fetchFilteredData Function
const fetchFilteredData = async (params: FilterProps, callBackFunc?: (appliedFilters: FilterProps) => void) => {
    try {
        await axios.get(url, params);
        callBackFunc?.()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error is: ', error)
    }
}

Or, you can also modify only your onApply function as,
const onApply = async (appliedFilters: FilterProps) => {
    setFilter(appliedFIlters)
    await fetchFilteredData(appliedFIlters)
}

But this will not be suggested. As, if API get fails, the filter will still be updated with the Applied filters.

I am not sure how will it solve the problem.
await fetchFilteredData(appliedFIlters, setFilter), here appliedFilters can still be outdated and not latest.

Can you share the actual Component, where onApply is written?

added codesandbox link

The  setTimeout is not a solution at all. It doesn't work any different than without the timeout.

In the code-sandbox example, you have used setFilter and the Apply filter one after another line. So, from this example, it will never fetch the current updated data.
I would suggest you, use the Formik state and its context over the ContextAPI state. So, on submit/apply, always you will get the updated state only.

Update: for keeping the updated values local until button action
If you need an option to reset the changes until the apply button is triggered, then you need a local state as well. In such case the following example can be referred.
// User.tsx
export default function Users() {
  const {
    filters: intialFilters,
    applyFilters,
  } = useFilters();
  const filters = useState(intialFilters);

  const filterControls: FilterControl[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: <InputBoxFilter label="First name" filterKey="fname" filters={filters} setFilter={setFilter} />,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: <InputBoxFilter label="Last name" filterKey="lname" filters={filters} setFilter={setFilter} />,
    },
  ];

  function onApply() {
    console.log("Making fetch call with following filters");
    Object.keys(filters).map((key) => console.log(`${key} : ${filters[key]}`));
    applyFilters(filters)
  }

  ...
}

Here we are creating a local filter and passing the setters and getters to InputBoxFilter components, so that we have a local state and a global state. Global state can be updated on the InputBoxFilter callback from context.

Based on your CodeSandbox Demo Link
I think the issue is in InputBoxFilter component where you have 2 state to capture the filterValue.
const { filters, setFilter, applyFilters } = useFilters();
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(filters[filterKey] || "");

If you don't need a local state in the component, you can directly use filters to control your component
<input value={filters[filterKey]} />

This ensures that there is only one state for the input and before clicking the apply button, if you see it in the ui, you can expect the same in the api call.

Note:

In the provider instantiate the filter with default values to make the inputs controlled inputs. Or <input value={filters[filterKey] || ''} /> will work as well.
You cannot verify the solution in the codesandbox example as the trigger happens right after apply fn in the old InputBoxFilter component, but should be verifiable in the env where you are clicking the button fast enough (thus allowing to rerender the InputBoxFilter).
The context solution is async in nature by design. If the context update is so slow so that the time taken between the keyboard stroke and the value displayed in the input component is not acceptable, then you have to think about other sync solutions.
Sync solutions examples are usage for useRef, saving the date as url param, saving the data in global object etc. Let me know if you want to explore in those direct even though I recommend the async option.


thanks a lot @Sumith for your detailed analysis. Not using 2 states looks like a feasible solution. I would definitely want to understand those sync based solution. What will be the difference between directly using context state without 2 state v/s useRef?. Also not sure how this works - saving the date as url param.

also how is the overall filter controls design, is it good?

@MohammedShirhaan useRef in context will directly update the filterState without the need to rerender, so you can always expect the latest value in (ref.current). But the drawback is, you cannot expect to listen its value change in any of your components. So I would suggest to go with directly using context state

for saving the data as url param,  you dont need a context, instead whenever the value changes, put it in the url using react-router and listen for url param changes wherever you require. You can go for existing solution like use-query-params as well. But sync solutions might make your site unresponsible if not done correctly. It will also be a mess if you have filters for multiple component in the same view.

but there is a challenge with directly using context state in filter controls. There is a side panel, where user might make changes in controls, and then closes the panel without clicking apply filter button. In this case, the filter controls should reset the value on reopening filter panel with last applied filters.

Thats a different case altogether that might not be clearly mentioned earlier. I think in such case where you don't want to update the context value until the action is triggered, then I will suggest you to create a local filter state in Users component using useState(filter), then when calling applyFilters pass the local component filter state and internally update the context filter state. In this example you have to send setters and getters from Users component to InputBoxFilter component as params. Let me try to update the answer with some code.

Likely the simplest solution would be to add an effect to your DisplayContextStore component.
Something like:
useEffect(() => {
  // make fetch call with latest filter
  fetch(url, {
    // body, including filters
  });
  // but you may want to throttle this function
}, [filters]); // this should be recreated each time you update the filters which should trigger the effect

You are essentially trying to synchronize state with an external system. This is the entire purpose of useEffect.

yeah but I want to not make a fetch call for every change of filter control values. But instead want to fetch only when clicking on apply filters. This can be done using two states and useEffect, but can it be done using one state alone?

@MohammedShirhaan Ah, in that case the best way to guarantee you're not using stale values from the provider is to pass the current values of the input filters to the applyFilters function and change the implementation to fetch using those args.
Signature:

function applyFilters(newFilters) {}

